# Global variable inside multiple classes

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Twitter;

    class Twitter {

        function __construct()
        {
            $config = array ('api' => 'something', 'api_url' => 'something2');
        }

        // some code goes here

    }

    class TwitterConnection {

        function __construct()
        {
            $config = array ('api' => 'something', 'api_url' => 'something2');
        }

        // some code goes here

    }
?>
```

and so on - there will be more classes that uses $config variables.

Now, the question is: how can I define config only once, and make it accessible across all classes?

Thanks

Comment: You not use a config file? I use ZF and it has a pretty neat config setup. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different things in play here - config data storage, and config data representation and use.

For storage, as martswite commented above, you could have a config file.  You could also have config data stored in a database.

For data representation, you could have an array, like you've shown in your question, or a separate full-fledged object.

Usually, if you have objects that have a dependency on certain data in order to work, you pass (*inject*) that dependency into the object through its constructor.  So, roughly, something like this:

```
class Example
{
    private $dependency;

    public function __construct($dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // do something with $this->dependency
    }
}
```

This would be tedious to do manually if you had many objects which required the same dependency.  Thankfully, there are *dependency injection containers* which automate a lot of the process.  Where do you find these containers?  A Google search should yield results.  That said, Symfony seems like a popular option: http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/

All that said, there's a bit of a learning curve to understanding and using a DI container.  Still, it's probably the best way to go without introducing globals into your code.

Finally, just to give you an idea of how to use it, here's some pseudo-code:

```
// Load config data from file/db/some other source.  Use it to populate an object (most likely) or array

// Set up the DI container to automatically inject the config data into the objects which require it

// Profit
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a configuration object that reads from your data source (ini, db, php file ...) and populates itself. Then give it a getter so you can get the configuration properties stored within.

Something along the lines of `Config::get('someProperty')`

Once you have this object setup, you can pass it to the constructor of your classes so it can be used in inside.

```
class Twitter {
        function __construct($config) {
            $state = $config->get('someState');
        } 
}
```

You could also simply use it within your classes without injecting it by making it a static class (You could also just as easily create a new instance).

```
class Twitter {
        function __construct() {
            //Don't recommend this, better to inject it. 
            $state = Config::get('someState');
        } 
}
```

**EDIT**

The simplest config class that uses your *hardcoded* array would look something like this. Again, I suggest you move out your configuration out of your code.

```
class Config {
    private $opts   = array();

    public function __construct() {
        /**
         * Ideally opts should be coming from some kind of easy to
         * access configuration file
         * 
         */
        $this->opts   = array ('api' => 'something', 'api_url' => 'something2');
    }

    public function get($key) {
        if (isset($this->opts[$key])) {
            return $this->opts[$key];
        } 
        return false;
    }
}


class Twitter {
    function __construct($config) {
        echo $config->get('api');
    }
}

$config = new Config();
new Twitter($config);
```

You could also change the class a bit so that it works without needing an instance of itself.

Comment: Let's say I want a solution without using external configs (because of some requirements for this project).

Comment: @Johnny you don't need to use external configs. Just put that array you were using inside the `Config` class and write the getter so that it returns the values by picking data from the array keys.

Comment: good idea , but not sure is there a simplier solution, I would like to avoid creating Config class.

Comment: @Johnny not unless you use global variables, which aren't recommended. I added some sample code that uses a config class.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
namespace Twitter;
   $config = array ('api' => 'something', 'api_url' => 'something2');
   class Twitter {

      function __construct()
      {
          global $config;
      }
   }

  class TwitterConnection {

      function __construct()
      {
          global $config;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: This is really a bad practice, since it introduces an unnecessary hard dependency, which makes a lot of things (eg.: testing) much more complicated.

Comment: Is this the only way to go, without using external configs?